# How can I extract Spinner Layout id from AdapterView<?> parent?

Tags: android, spinner, dropdown, parent

This is my **onItemSelected** code for a **spinner**.

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // On selecting a spinner item
        String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        // Showing selected spinner item
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: "  , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("Value",parent.toString());
    }
```

When I print **parent.tostring** it gives me this:

```
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner{9f46108 VFED..C.. ......ID 552,31-942,169 #7f0800ee app:id/**spinner_walk**}
```

I want to extract the ***id/spinner_walk*** from there, is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the id of the spinner on which the onItemSelected listener is set you need to get the id of the adapterView i.e.

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // This will return the id of the selected spinner
    int id = adapterView.getId();

    if(id == R.id.spinner_walk){
      Toast.makeToast(context, "Spinner Walk selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```